# Iterative block diagonalisation in degenerate perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory

How is iterative block diagonalisation carried out in the matrix form of degenerate perturbation theory to lift degeneracy present in the zeroth-order or unperturbed Hamiltonian ($H_{0}$)? In general what would be the strategy to lift the degeneracies when there are $m$ blocks(or subspaces) of $\alpha_{m}$-fold degeneracy each.

The usual method it to  block diagonalise the degenerate subspaces of the perturbation matrix (say $V$, where $H = H_{0} + \lambda V$)  and then use those eigenvalues as first order correction for corresponding degenerate zeroth order energies. And we use the eigenvectors to get the first order corrections to the wave function. But, when degeneracy is not lifted first order due to *coincidental* or *accidental* degeneracies, it is said that one has to resort to iterative diagonalisation methods until these degeneracies are lifted and then for further higher order corrections non-degenerate perturbation theory can be used.

Comment: "it is said" -- source? (not doubting, just to get context)

Comment: @Andrew My source is hear-say, I myself don't know much, hence the question.